# Randomness of hashing functions such as SHA1

Tags: php, random, sha

I'm trying to generate an even distribution of random numbers based on User IDs.  That is, I want a random number for each user that remains the same any time that user requests the random number (but the user doesn't need to store the number).  My current algorithm (in PHP) to count distribution, for a given large array of userIDs `$arr` is:

```
$range = 100;
$results = array_fill(0, $range, 0);

foreach ($arr as $userID) {
    $hash = sha1($userID,TRUE);
    $data = unpack('L*', $hash);
    $seed = 0;
    foreach ($data as $integer) {
        $seed ^= $integer;
    }
    srand($seed);
    ++$results[rand(0, $range-1)];
}
```

One would hope that this generates an approximately even distribution.  But it doesn't!  I've checked to make sure that each value in `$arr` is unique, but one entry in the list always gets much more activity than all the others.  Is there a better method of generating a hash of a string that will give an approximately even distribution?  Apparently SHA is not up to the job.  I've also tried MD5 and a simple crc32, all with the same results!?

Am I crazy?  Is the only explanation that I have not, in fact, verified that each entry in `$arr` is unique?

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you requesting. You want a unique random number for each user? Why not `sha1($userId . $salt)`?

Comment: There's some bits missing. I can't run this code and see what you mean by "one entry gets much more activity". You should also note that SHA-1 isn't designed to be random, it's designed to be pseudo-random with low collision rate over 2^160 combinations. I think I read somewhere that the random generator in PHP gets "more random" with each subsequent call, so your call directly after seeding it may not be enough. Give it a go with mt_rand and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect random anything to be evenly distributed, even when setting the seed. even using a for loop with numbers 1-100 as the seed it isn't evenly distributed. http://codepad.viper-7.com/LxeHhu 3 numbers come up 3 times while 31/100 numbers come up 0 times.

Comment: Is response to your comment below, if you want to generate a user_id for a user from their username with a somewhat even distribution, you could just sha1/md5 the username and hexdec part of it. It won't be within the range you specified (could be with modulus), but it would have better distribution. http://codepad.viper-7.com/qkSfaE <-- using the last 5 numbers from a sha1 of all numbers 1-10,000, only 46 numbers come up 2 times. This could be decreased further by using more of the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mt_rand()` should have a very even distribution over the range requested.  When users are created, create a random seed for that user using `mt_rand()` then always `mt_srand()` with that seed for that user.

To get an even distribution from 0 to 99, as your example, just `mt_rand(0,$range-1)`.  Doing tricks with sha1, md5, or some other hashing algorithm won't really give you a more even distribution than straight random.

Comment: The reason for my somewhat confusing requirements is that I don't store user IDs. A user simply sends its id to the server, and the server must always return the same value for that user, with an approximately even distribution over all user IDs.  So, storing any user data is outside the scope of the function.

Comment: So essentially the user is sending you a seed value, right?  If you pass their input to `mt_srand()` the `mt_rand()` function will always return the same number(s) for that user.

Comment: I will accept your answer because the use of mt_rand is probably a good idea, although if my data were actually unique (I had apparently not gotten rid of duplicates) my original algorithm would have worked.

Comment: Aha, source data collisions! =)

Answer (score 6):

The sha1 hash numbers are quite uniform distributed. After executing this:

```
<?php

$n = '';
$salt = 'this is the salt';

for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
    $n .= implode('', unpack('L*', sha1($i . $salt)));
}   

$count = count_chars($n, 1);
$sum = array_sum($count);

foreach ($count as $k => $v) {
    echo chr($k)." => ".($v/$sum)."\n";
} 

?>
```

You get this result. The probability for each number:

```
0 => 0.083696057956298
1 => 0.12138983759522
2 => 0.094558704004335
3 => 0.07301783188663
4 => 0.092124978934097
5 => 0.088623772577848
6 => 0.11390989553446
7 => 0.092570936094051
8 => 0.12348330833868
9 => 0.11662467707838
```

You could use the sha1 as a simple random number generator based on the user's id.

In hexadecimal, the distribution is near to perfect:

```
//  $n .= sha1($i . $salt, false);

0 => 0.06245515
1 => 0.06245665
2 => 0.06258855
3 => 0.0624244
4 => 0.06247255
5 => 0.0625422
6 => 0.0625246
7 => 0.0624716
8 => 0.06257355
9 => 0.0625005
a => 0.0625068
b => 0.0625086
c => 0.0624463
d => 0.06250535
e => 0.06250895
f => 0.06251425
```

Comment: @Marty. Yup. You should not be using the sha1 result as a seed to mt_rand. Sha1 by itself is a good enough hash.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your results that led you to conclude that you're not getting an appropriate distribution, but it's likely one of three things is going on here:

1. You're simply looking at too small of a sample, and/or you're miss-interpreting your data.  As others have commented, it's completely reasonable for a uniform distribution to not have perfectly uniform output.
2. You'd see better results if you used [`mt_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead of `rand`.
3. (Personally, I think this is most likely) You're over-optimizing your seed generation, and losing data / pigeon holing / otherwise hurting your ability to generate random numbers.  Reading your code, I think you're doing the following:

   1. Generate a uniform random hash of an unknown value
   2. Split the hash into longs and bitwise XOR-ing them together
   3. Setting `rand`'s seed, and generating a random number off that seed

   But why are you doing step 2?  What benefit do you think you're getting from that?  Try taking that step out, and just use the first value you extract from the hash as your seed, and see if that doesn't give you better results.  Good rule of thumb with randomness - don't try to outsmart the people who implemented the algorithms, it can't be done :)

Comment: As for sample size, 300,000 unique values should be large enough I hope.  You're basically right about what im trying to do.  The original value I'm given from the user is a long string, which can't be used to seed a rng.  So my first step is to convert it to a raw sha hash.  However, that's a raw binary string 20 bytes in length, which still can't be used as a seed, so I need step 2 to convert it to an integer.  Unless there's a better way?

Comment: Just take the front bytes as your seed (or even just use it directly as your unique value), that's plenty of randomness, no need to try to collapse the bits together.

Answer (score 0):

While all of the answers here are good, I will provide the answer that was correct for me, and that is that I was, indeed, crazy.  Apparently the `uniq` command does not, in fact, work like I expected it to (data needs to be sorted first).  So the explanation was indeed that the values in `$arr` were not unique.